# SQL , Analytical Functions , rownumber

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I need to get same rownumber or numeric value in SQL to group values that match conditions like the following example:

If we have same Agent name and the time variance between current row and preceding row value is less than 06:00 hours after applying partition by name and ordering by time 
then add same rownumber else increase it.

example for row data and output of rownumber:

```
person  date_time   rownumber
A   01/04/2018 10:00    1
A   01/04/2018 13:00    1
A   01/04/2018 14:00    1
A   01/04/2018 15:00    1
A   01/04/2018 23:00    2
A   02/04/2018 03:00    2
A   02/04/2018 12:00    3
A   02/04/2018 16:00    3
B   01/04/2018 17:00    4
B   01/04/2018 20:30    4
C   01/04/2018 18:00    5
C   01/04/2018 22:00    5
```

Comment: Which version of oracle are you using?

Comment: You need LAG / LEAD analytic function. Check this: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions

Comment: Oracle 12c , I used LAG and LEAD but how we can control rownumber increment using case statement knowing that sequence and rownumber functions don't serve us

Comment: Please I need the select statement which returns rownumber mentioned in my example based on the condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of LAG and SUM analytic functions, like so:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 'A' person, to_date('01/04/2018 10', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') date_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'A' person, to_date('01/04/2018 13', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') date_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'A' person, to_date('01/04/2018 14', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') date_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'A' person, to_date('01/04/2018 15', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') date_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'A' person, to_date('01/04/2018 23', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') date_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'A' person, to_date('02/04/2018 03', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') date_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'A' person, to_date('02/04/2018 12', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') date_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'A' person, to_date('02/04/2018 16', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') date_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'B' person, to_date('01/04/2018 17', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') date_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'B' person, to_date('01/04/2018 20', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') date_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'C' person, to_date('01/04/2018 18', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') date_time FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'C' person, to_date('01/04/2018 22', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24') date_time FROM dual)
SELECT person,
       date_time,
       SUM(period_change) OVER (ORDER BY person, date_time) rownumber
FROM   (SELECT person,
               date_time,
               CASE WHEN date_time - LAG(date_time, 1, date_time - 7/24) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY date_time) > 6/24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END period_change
        FROM   your_table);

PERSON DATE_TIME    ROWNUMBER
------ ----------- ----------
A      01/04/2018           1
A      01/04/2018           1
A      01/04/2018           1
A      01/04/2018           1
A      01/04/2018           2
A      02/04/2018           2
A      02/04/2018           3
A      02/04/2018           3
B      01/04/2018           4
B      01/04/2018           4
C      01/04/2018           5
C      01/04/2018           5
```

This works by putting 1 in the additional column whenever a new group is triggered.

Once you have that, then you can do a running sum on that column. That means that after every group change, subsequent rows will be assigned the same number, up until the next group change.

N.B. As suggested by Peter Lang in the comments below, you might prefer to change the case statement generating the "period_change" column to:

```
CASE WHEN date_time - LAG(date_time) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY date_time) < 6/24 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: I would suggest to invert the logic (and then using `<` instead of `<=` since asking for _less than 06:00 hours_) to avoid the `default` parameter of `LAG`: `CASE WHEN date_time - LAG(date_time) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY date_time) < 6/24 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END period_change`. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks dear for your support